# Design test with templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

I have a question regarding a design in C++.
As you see in the code below there is a design problem. I want to be able to have a `TestClass` which inherits from zero or more classes derived from `ModeBase` (`ModeOne` and `ModeTwo` in this example). If `TestClass` inherits from `ModeOne`, it would have the ability to use `MethodeOne()`, and it would be a requirement for `TestClass` to implement `MethodOne()` which is what I want.

```
class ModeBase
{
//--Methods--------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
    virtual ~ModeBase() = default;
};

class ModeOne : private ModeBase
{
//--Methods--------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
    virtual ~ModeOne() = default;

    virtual void MethodOne() {}
};

class ModeTwo : private ModeBase
{
//--Methods--------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
    virtual ~ModeTwo() = default;

    virtual void MethodTwo() {}
};



class TestBase
{
//--Methods--------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
    TestBase() : currentMode_( nullptr ) {}

    virtual ~TestBase() = default;

    template <class Mode, class T>
    void ChangeMode()
    {
        if( std::is_base_of<Mode, T>::value )
        {
            // Class does inherit from Mode so we make sure the current mode
            // has changed
            currentMode_ = std::make_shared<Mode>();
        }
        else
        {
            // Class does not inherit from Mode so we don't do anything
        }
    }

    template <class Mode>
    bool CurrentMode()
    {
        if( std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Mode>(currentMode_) != nullptr )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

//--Data members---------------------------------------------------------------
private:
    std::shared_ptr<ModeBase> currentMode_;
};

class TestOne
    : public TestBase
    , private ModeOne
    , private ModeTwo
{
//--Methods--------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~TestOne() = default;

    void HeartbeatTick()
    {
        if( CurrentMode<ModeOne>() )
        {
            MethodOne();
        }
        else if( CurrentMode<ModeTwo>() )
        {
            MethodTwo();
        }
    }

    virtual void MethodOne() {}
    virtual void MethodTwo() {}
};


class SomeManager
{
    ~SomeManager() = default;

    void ChangeAllMode()
    {
        for( auto it = vector_.begin(); it != vector_.end(); ++it )
        {
            // Here is the problem with this implementation. I need to know
            // the type of the TestBase derived class (TestOne) to use it as
            // a `ChangeMode` method template parameter.
            //(*it)->ChangeMode<AIModeFollowLine, SOMETYPE>();
        }
    };

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TestBase>> vector_;
};
```

I already know this is bad design since `vector_` will be filled at runtime so I have no way of using `ChangeMode` like that. It appears that it would be a good solution to use multimethods, wouldn't it ? If so, what would the design look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just being stupid here !
I just have to use a different `ChangeMode()` method in order to know if `TestBase` and thus `TestOne` is of type `ModeBase`:

```
template<typename Mode>
bool
IsSame( TestBase* base )
{
     return dynamic_cast<Mode*>(base) != nullptr;
};

template <class Mode>
void
ChangeMode()
{
    if( isSame<Mode>(this) )
    {
        // Change the ticker method
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multimethods (AKA multiple dispatch) deals with the issue of dispatching a call to a single function based on the runtime type of the parameters involved. This does not appear to be your issue (or have I misunderstood you?), as you have two different method names, implemented on two different types.

Your goal appears to be to select a method implementation based on a runtime type that you have injected into a class. It is not clear whether you are able to dictate the form which that injection takes but if you are then why do you not directly inject the implementation? Then you could use an **implicit interface** rather than an explicit one. In other words why not inject a `functor`-like object?

```
class TestBase
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void ()> Ticker;

    TestBase(Ticker hbTicker) : ticker{hbTicker} {}

    void HeartbeatTick() {
       ticker();
    }

    void setTicker(Ticker hbTicker){
        ticker = hbTicker;
    }

private:
    Ticker ticker;
};
```

Seems like a lot less complicated to me if that meets your requirements.

If you really do need to implement multiple dispatch you will probably need to implement a `visitor` pattern on each of the parameters whose runtime type you need to determine. Not sure if that would work for multiple parameters though (I've not tried multiple parameters myself at least). Or you could use `RTTI` and a case statement or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would also like to change the ticker at runtine depending on a type injected by `SomeManager::ChangeAllMode`. When the injection takes place, if `TestOne` is derived from the injected type (`ModeOne` or `ModeTwo`) then we can set the ticker.

Comment: But `TestBase` does not know if the derived class `TestOne` is derived from those types or not...

Comment: @Athanase What is the problem? If you want to globally use the same functionality in `all` your classes then have the manager just set all the function objects to the new functionality. Or use a global pointer and inject it into the desired objects, then change what that pointer points to. As far as I can see there is no reason for the complexity of your solution.